# What does the Report builder profile permission control in SFDC?

Tags: reporting, permissions, profile

What does the Report builder profile permission control?  If i have this permission unchecked and the create and customize permission set, i am still able to use the report builder.  If i have the Report builder permission set and create and customize unchecked, then its as good as run report, i am not able to customize or create reports.

Answer (score 2):

http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_reports_and_dashboards_reportbuilder_upgrade.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_builder_editing.htm

Just go through these links. Hope this helps.

Comment: Relevant portion of the first link: "All profiles get access to the report builder by default. (You may continue to see the “Report Builder” permission in permission sets and profiles and the PermissionSet and Profile objects in the API, though the upgrade overrides those settings.) The old report wizard will be available only to users in Accessibility Mode."

Answer (score 2):

The Report Builder permission gives the user the ability to "Create, edit, and delete reports through the drag-and-drop report builder interface." This is the newer reporting tool. The separate permission "Create and Customize Reports" is the one that allows the user to work with reports at all.

Here's a list of [all permissions available on the profile](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_userperms.htm&language=en_US) and in permission sets.